# How to prepend (and append) to string if it contains a whitespace character?

Tags: python, pandas

here is what i've tried:

```
df[df.path.str.contains(" ", na=False)] = df['^' + df.path.astype('str') + '$']
```

this gives me an error though.
Basically what I tried was to set the 'path' column to the same value with one character prepended (and appended). But I tried to set only the rows that contain a single whitespace.

complete stack trace (I'm working in a local jupyter notebok):

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[180], line 22
     17 df['path'] = df.path.str.replace(" ", "$|^")
     18 #print(df[df.path.str.contains("\$\|\^", na=False)].shape[0])
     19 
     20 #multipath = df[df.path.str.contains(" ", na=False)]
     21 #multipath['path'] = multipath['path'].str.replace(' ','$|^')
---> 22 df[df.path.str.contains(" ", na=False)] = df['^' + df.path.astype('str') + '$']
     23 #multipath['path'] = 
     24 #print(multipath.shape[0])
     27 print("original shape:", df.shape[0])

File ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3902, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3900     if is_iterator(key):
   3901         key = list(key)
-> 3902     indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
   3904 # take() does not accept boolean indexers
   3905 if getattr(indexer, "dtype", None) == bool:

File ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:6114, in Index._get_indexer_strict(self, key, axis_name)
   6111 else:
   6112     keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = self._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
-> 6114 self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
   6116 keyarr = self.take(indexer)
   6117 if isinstance(key, Index):
   6118     # GH 42790 - Preserve name from an Index

File ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:6175, in Index._raise_if_missing(self, key, indexer, axis_name)
   6173     if use_interval_msg:
   6174         key = list(key)
-> 6175     raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   6177 not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())
   6178 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")

KeyError: "None of [Index(['^nan$',\n       '^/content/icebreakers/en_us/products/ice-cubes-wintergreen-1-5-oz-tins-8-ct-box.html$',\n       '^/content/corporate_SSF/en_us/careers/retirees/contact-us.html$',\n       '^/content/franchise/en_us/products.html$',\n       '^/content/franchise/en_us/our-brands/good-and-plenty/good-and-plenty-1-8-oz.html$',\n       '^/content/dam/chocolateworld/en_us/documents/times-square-reopening-menu.pdf$',\n       '^/content/franchise/en_us/products/hersheys-milk-chocolate-snack-size-bag.html$',\n       '^/content/jolly-rancher/en_us/products/orignal-hard-candy-60-oz.html$',\n       '^/content/kitkat/en_us/products/white-bar.html$',\n       '^/content/dam/chocolateworld/en_us/documents/birthday-party-packages.pdf$',\n       ...\n       '^/kitchens/en_us/recipes/grilled-peanut-butter-chocolate-and-jelly-sandwich.html$',\n       '^/kitchens/en_us/recipes/apple-wheels.html$',\n       '^/whoppers/en_us/products/strawberry-milkshake.html$',\n       '^/kitchens/en_us/blogs/chocolate-covered-valentines-day.html$',\n       '^/en_us/our-brands/bubble-yum/bubble-yum-cotton-candy-5-piece.html$|^/en_us/our-brands/bubble-yum/bubble-yum-sugarless-original-10-piece.html$',\n       '^/en_us/ad-cookie-policy.html$',\n       '^/hersheysolutions/en_us/employee_register.html$',\n       '^/reeses/en_us/products/$|^/en_us/our-brands/milk-duds/milk-duds-snack-size-chewy-caramels-9-3-oz.html$|^/reeses/en_us/products/reeses-peanut-butter-eggs-6-pack.html$|^/reeses/en_us/products/reeses-chocolate-lovers-cups.html$',\n       '^nan$', '^/content/corporate_SSF/en_us/investors.html$'],\n      dtype='object', length=4586)] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: The error is produced because in `df['^' + df.path.astype('str') + '$']` you are using your target string as index.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more explicit to add an example of your data, but I believe you can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['path'].str.contains(" ", na=False)

df.loc[m, 'path'] = '^' + df.loc[m, 'path'].astype(str) + '$'
```

`df['^' + df.path.astype('str') + '$']` doesn't make sense since this would be using the concatenation as indexer to slice columns.

Comment: brilliant, this is exactly what I was looking for! I never quite understood the purpose of `loc()`.